# Use dynamic TextField in ListViewBuilder in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to build a dynamic TextField list in flutter but did not understand at how I can handle it.

My list looks like this:

My code structure is:

[image]

```
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              
              if(itemList.length == null) {
                return _buildProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                return singleItemList(index);
              }
          })




Widget singleItemList(int index) {

if((itemList.length -1) < index)
{
  return Container(child: null); 
} else {

  dynamic singleItem = itemList[index];
  String counter = (index+1).toString();

  return 
     Container(
        
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),

      child: Row(    
        
        children:[

          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text(counter,style: orderBookItemListCounter(),)
          ),

           

          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: TextField(
                controller: _addProductToCart(counter),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Qty",
                ),
            )
          ),

    ])
  );
}
}
```

1. My product list is not fixed may change the number of products,
2. I would like to capture Qty as per product ID.

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several options depending how you architecture your application or where you have your central state.

I propose you here a solution that updates a local map variable. Alternatively, you could send an event/stream to the place your store is located.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Item> itemList = [
    Item("ID1", "First product"),
    Item("ID2", "Second product"),
  ];

  Map<String, int> quantities = {};

  void takeNumber(String text, String itemId) {
    try {
      int number = int.parse(text);
      quantities[itemId] = number;
      print(quantities);
    } on FormatException {}
  }

  Widget singleItemList(int index) {
    Item item = itemList[index];

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("${index + 1}")),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (text) {
                takeNumber(text, item.id);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Qty",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (itemList.isEmpty) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                return singleItemList(index);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Item(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it just worked perfectly. But have little issue here `takeNumber` this function call on every key press. mean when user like to add two digit of qty it call twice..

Comment: There is also `onSubmitted:` in the textfield but you must press it after finishing typing. If you leave the textfield withoug pressing the button in the keyboard, nothing is stored. Try it by replacing `onChanged:` by `onSubmitted:`

Comment: And you could also add a `FocusNode` to every textfield so whenever you it loses focus you can save the value. You can add a listener to the focusnode for this.

Comment: Otherwise you could wrap your page with a `Form` so when you submit the form all values are saved.

Answer (score 6):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}



class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = new List();
  List<Item> itemList = [
    Item("ID1", "product 1"),
    Item("ID2", "product 2"),
    Item("ID3", "product 3"),
    Item("ID4", "product 4"),
    Item("ID5", "product 5"),
    Item("ID6", "product 6"),
    Item("ID7", "product 7"),
    Item("ID8", "product 8"),
    Item("ID9", "product 9"),
    Item("ID10", "product 10"),
    Item("ID11", "product 11"),
    Item("ID12", "product 12"),
    Item("ID13", "product 13"),
    Item("ID14", "product 14"),
    Item("ID15", "product 15"),
    Item("ID16", "product 16"),
    Item("ID17", "product 17"),
    Item("ID18", "product 18"),



  ];



  Map<String, int> quantities = {};

  void takeNumber(String text, String itemId) {
    try {
      int number = int.parse(text);
      quantities[itemId] = number;
      print(quantities);
    } on FormatException {}
  }



  Widget singleItemList(int index, TextEditingController controllertxt) {
    Item item = itemList[index];

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [


          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("${index + 1}")),

          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: new TextField(
              controller: controllertxt,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (text) {
                takeNumber(text, item.id);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Qty",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
              if (itemList.isEmpty) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {

                return singleItemList(index,_controllers[index]);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}




class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Item(this.id, this.name);
}
```