# Change text in a TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form with many `TextFormField` that are dynamically loaded inside a `ListView.builder`, the problem is that I want to change the text of only one `TextFromField` but I change the text of all the TextFromField using `TextEditingController` and it is because all my TextFormField are using the same controller, is there any way to change the text of just one `TextFormField` no matter exactly what`TextFormField` is?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Here is the `ListView.builder` with the `TextFormField`:

```html
class ListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final Preguntas preguntas;
  final formKey;
  ListBuilder({@required this.preguntas, this.formKey});
  Preguntas preguntasGlobal = Preguntas();
  @override
  _ListBuilderState createState() => _ListBuilderState();
}

class _ListBuilderState extends State<ListBuilder> {
  var textController = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true, 
          itemCount: widget.preguntas.secciones[0].preguntas.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i){
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  controller: textController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular", color: Color(0xffe81935)),
                    hintMaxLines: 500,
                    hintText: widget.preguntas.secciones[0].preguntas[i].respuestas[0].pregunta.descripcion,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular", fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value){}
                ),
              ],
            ); 
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer you are looking for [Use dynamic TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779759/use-dynamic-textfield-in-listviewbuilder-in-flutter)

Comment: Is it must to have controller? What are you specifically trying to achieve with controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incorrect to use one `TextEditingController` for multiple text fields. You should create one controller per text field.

I would do like this:

```dart
class _ListBuilderState extends State<ListBuilder> {
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers;
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    // Pre-create controllers:
    _controllers = List<TextEditingController>.generate(
        widget.preguntas.secciones[0].preguntas.length, (index) => TextEditingController());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true, 
          itemCount: widget.preguntas.secciones[0].preguntas.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i){
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  // Access a controller by index.
                  controller: _controllers[i],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular", color: Color(0xffe81935)),
                    hintMaxLines: 500,
                    hintText: widget.preguntas.secciones[0].preguntas[i].respuestas[0].pregunta.descripcion,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular", fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value){}
                ),
              ],
            ); 
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```